# Is there any method to transfer files between docker container using python scripts?

Tags: python, docker

Project in container A and has a function to restore data,which may need to send files to container B
Or I should not do like this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A typical approach is to send things back and forth using HTTP requests.  I'd avoid trying to "share files" between containers, which can be tricky to set up and doesn't scale well to other container environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using volume option when you run container A & B

`docker run -t imagename:tag -v 'data path shared on local': path data on container A` container A

`docker run -t imagename:tag -v 'data path shared on local': path data on container B` container B

when restore new file in container A in access in path local and container B could used it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `docker-compose` and a shared volume between your containers.